# Ng-selected not working angular js 1.6.5

Tags: angularjs

I have tried the following code and failed to get the select option working.

HTML:

```
 <select class=" form-control input-sm" ng-model="formCompletionData.myFilter" ng-change="myFilterChange(formCompletionData.myFilter)">
   <option value="">--select--</option>
   <option ng-repeat="filter in myfilter" ng-selected="filter.isDefault==true" value="{{filter.filtername}}">{{filter.myfiltername}}</option>
 </select>
```

Angular Code:

```
 $scope.formCompletionData={};
```

This is the json reponse for $scope.myfilter:

so $scope.myfilter looks like this:

```
[      {  
  "_id":"598d8d9998ebb08100fdc272",
  "createdBy":"58A559634025FD4867EDAB81",
  "myfiltername":"Test",
  "filtername":"5A30DA2EB2D0FB046899AED3",
  "groupname":"",
  "status":"",
  "isDefault":true,
  "customerId":"SMRTsspd"    },    {  
  "_id":"598da8ec98ebfdceb09d9f4c",
  "createdBy":"58A559634025FD4867EDAB81",
  "myfiltername":"test2",
  "filtername":"5A30DA2EB2D0FB046899AED3",
  "groupname":"59DDE8584B28AFFC49E47C89",
  "status":"0",
  "isDefault":false,
  "customerId":"SMRTsspd"    },    {  
  "_id":"598da8fd98ebfdceb09d9f4d",
  "createdBy":"58A559634025FD4867EDAB81",
  "myfiltername":"test66",
  "alluser":false,
  "filtername":"594CCAB14B289B198AC85360",
  "groupname":"5926C668B7A2B94251CA2EC6",
  "status":"1",
  "isDefault":false,
  "customerId":"SMRTsspd"    } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my code below, it is working fine.

```js
angular.module("App", [])
    .controller("DemoController", function($scope) {
      $scope.formCompletionData = {};
      $scope.myfilter = [{
      "_id":"598d8d9998ebb08100fdc272",
      "createdBy":"58A559634025FD4867EDAB81",
      "myfiltername":"Test",
      "filtername":"5A30DA2EB2D0FB046899AED3",
      "groupname":"",
      "status":"",
      "isDefault":false,
      "customerId":"SMRTsspd"    },    {  
      "_id":"598da8ec98ebfdceb09d9f4c",
      "createdBy":"58A559634025FD4867EDAB81",
      "myfiltername":"test2",
      "filtername":"5A30DA2EB2D0FB046899AED3",
      "groupname":"59DDE8584B28AFFC49E47C89",
      "status":"0",
      "isDefault":false,
      "customerId":"SMRTsspd"    },    {  
      "_id":"598da8fd98ebfdceb09d9f4d",
      "createdBy":"58A559634025FD4867EDAB81",
      "myfiltername":"test66",
      "alluser":false,
      "filtername":"594CCAB14B289B198AC85360",
      "groupname":"5926C668B7A2B94251CA2EC6",
      "status":"1",
      "isDefault":true,
      "customerId":"SMRTsspd"}];

      $scope.selectFilter = function(filter) {
   $scope.formCompletionData.myFilter=filter;
   return true;
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="DemoController">
    <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="formCompletionData.myFilter" ng-change="myFilterChange(formCompletionData.myFilter)">
     <option value="">--select--</option>
     <option ng-repeat="filter in myfilter" ng-selected="filter.isDefault==true && selectFilter(filter.filtername)" value="{{filter.filtername}}">{{filter.myfiltername}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: ya nice but here you used angular 1.2 but i am using using angular 1.6 so kindly check it the issue.

Comment: Okay, see now, I have updated snippet. I tried with 1.6.5 in my local and working fine.

Comment: If still you face any problem, let me know.